# Why is silver(I) oxide sensitive to a long period exposure to the light?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, photochemistry

I will do a reaction where I will use silver oxide as a catalyst (Lewis acid) that will help me to do a nucleophilic substitution. I read that it is photosensitive but I could not find the reason why it is.

I wrote this equation but I am not even sure this what happens when it is exposed to light:

$$\ce{2 \overset{+1}{Ag}_2O -> 4 \overset{0}{Ag} + O2}$$

Comment: Remember the analogical reaction in the classical film material with AgBr,

Comment: @Poutnik I don't know this analogical reaction...

Comment: Getting to know it does not take much more time than writing you do not know it. // $\ce{2 AgBr ->[light] 2 Ag + Br2 ->[gelatin][-Br2] 2 Ag}$

Comment: @Poutnik I did'nt find that anywhere that is why. This compound was actually used during a reaction with nitrobromobenzene and primary alcool. The goal of it was to accelerate the reaction. But they told us to keep it in dark so I was just thinking what could happen to my reaction if I let it in the light

Comment: Contrary to the fact that many silver compounds are photosensitive, silver oxide is not photosensitive, although it readily decomposes at temperatures above 280 °C.